# Why is eclipse asking me to add a return statement in this code even when I've added one?

Tags: java

Here is the code snippet:

```
private double input()throws IOException
{

    StringTokenizer st=null;
    BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvfile));
    String line=null;
    int count=0;
    while((line=b.readLine())!=null)
    {
        count+=1;
        if(count==0)
        {
            return 0.0;
        }
        else
        {   
            int sum=0;
            String[]  arr=new String[19];
            st=new StringTokenizer(line,",");
            int i=0;
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                arr[i]=st.nextToken();
                i++;
            }

            for(int j=2;j<arr.length;j++)
            {
                if(j==13)
                {
                    return Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);      
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I've added a return statement for both cases of the `if-else` ladder. `Eclipse` is still asking me to add a return statement. Execution of the code raises an error for the same reason.(error : `This method must return a result of type double`)Why is this happening?

Background: The above method is to read a CSV file and return certain sections of the file as per the  requirements of another method, which hasn't been shown here.

Comment: Can you fix the indentation of your code?  It looks like the final brace of the `while` loop is actually the final brace of the `else` block, which makes your statement "As you can see I've added a return statement for both cases of the if-else ladder" sound untrue until looking at the code more closely.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Is it better now ?

Comment: @JaneLove No, it's not better yet;  the `for` loop is still at the same level as the `else` block, but should be farther to the right, since it's inside the `else` block.

Comment: You have few suggestions in the answers to solve this, the bottom line is that you have to provide a single return for each possible path your workflow may take. So you will see this error if there is at least 1 way to reach a no way out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What happens `if(j==13)` returns `false` and never executes corresponding `return`? there is no `return` statement for this execution path right?

You need to have `return` statement for all executable paths.

Comment: Just to add, even if logic guarantees that a return must be reached, one may encounter a runtime exception, and even without regard to that, the analyzer is quite dumb.

Comment: `if(x>5)return true; if(x<=5)return false;` will generate a compile error

Comment: @Cruncher:  I see. Compiler is not that intelligent enough to figure out that one of  x>5 or x<=5 will always be true, so it asks for what happens if none of those becomes true for some reason. so, technically compilers see 3 possible execution paths.

Comment: Nambari, I think that @Cruncher's point was an example of the point that was making hexafraction's comment;  we recognize that at least one of `x>5` and `x<=5` must be true, so at least one of those paths must return, but the compiler doesn't to the _semantic analysis_ to draw that same conclusion.

Comment: It seems trivial for cases like this, but to analyze your program's logic to see if you're guarenteed to hit a return, would be computationally difficult, and not grant much convenience to the programmer. It's not hard to follow the syntax to guarentee. At the end of the day, if you know you'll hit a return, you can return a dummy value at the end, or some kind of assertion

Answer (score 3):

There are several execution paths in your method that don't end in a `return` statement. All of them must do so. For example, the `while` loop might never be entered.

The easiest way to be absolutely sure is to add a `return` statement with a default value as the last statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `else` block `return` statement is going to execute,So you have to declare `return` statement outside.
In your case it is good practice to declare a variable outside and assigns it in `if` and `else` block and return it.
example:

```
double returnVariable = 0.0;
if(count==0)
{
   returnVariable  =0.0;
}
else
{
   returnVariable = Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);
}
................
...........
return returnVariable ;
```

Comment: There _is_ a guarantee that either the _then_ block or the _else_ block will execute, so having an unconditional `return` in each would be fine.  The problem here is that the `return` in the _else_ block is conditional, and may not be encountered.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is after this statement:

```
for (int j=2; j < arr.length; j++) {
  if (j == 13) {
    return Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);      
  }
}
```

If nothing is returned in that loop, Java is expecting you to return something afterwards. Java has no way to tell that the condition in the `if` is going to be true at some point, and in fact, it might never be true (what would happen if the array had less than 13 elements?).

The solution is to simply add an extra `return` at the end, with a returned value that makes it clear that the method exited under a non-expected circumstance - for example, if `j` was never equal to `13`. Just add `return -1.0;` in the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Your else part doesn't have a return statement directly. Instead it has it inside another if statement. Compiler can't determine if you will hot this check and returns.

Answer (score 0):

In this section:

```
    for(int j=2;j<arr.length;j++)
    {
        if(j==13)
        {
            return Double.parseDouble(arr[j]);      
        }
    }
```

If you make it all the way through your loop, and don't find j = 13 (regardless if j is guaranteed to be there logically or not, programmatically that can't be determined by the compiler), then there is no applicable `return` statement.

You need to add a default case `return` statement AFTER your `for` loop.